# Making things public

Tags: kotlin, corda

Is there a way to design a contract that allows new nodes joining the network to discover some UTXO + its history?

One can add state transition in the contract that adds new party to the conversation but this requires transaction for each join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by writing a flow pair that allows joining nodes to request specific existing transactions from other nodes that are already on the network.

Here is an example dummy implementation:

```
@InitiatingFlow
@StartableByRPC
class Initiator(val txIdToRequest: SecureHash, val partyToRequestFrom: Party) : FlowLogic<SignedTransaction>() {
    @Suspendable
    override fun call(): SignedTransaction {
        val sessionWithPartyToRequestFrom = initiateFlow(partyToRequestFrom)
        val untrustworthyData = sessionWithPartyToRequestFrom.sendAndReceive<SignedTransaction>(txIdToRequest)
        val requestedTx = untrustworthyData.unwrap { tx -> tx }
        return requestedTx
    }
}

@InitiatedBy(Initiator::class)
class Responder(val counterpartySession: FlowSession) : FlowLogic<Unit>() {
    @Suspendable
    override fun call() {
        val untrustworthyData = counterpartySession.receive<SecureHash>()
        val requestedTxId = untrustworthyData.unwrap { id -> id }
        val requestedTx = serviceHub.validatedTransactions.getTransaction(requestedTxId)!!
        counterpartySession.send(requestedTx)
    }
}
```

Comment: So, the new nodes use `Party(CordaX500Name, PublicKey)` to start the flow that uses `SendTransactionFlow` to notify them about the transactions?

Comment: I added a dummy implementation.